# Change the textview text color when button is clicked in android

Tags: java, android

I have a code for a Quiz Game in Android Studio. I need to change the color of text in textview when my answer is correct, but in my code the button color change when the question is the next. I click to the correct answer but the color put in the next question. Can you help me?

```
respuesta1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(respuesta1.getText() == respuestaCorrecta){  //if the answer is correct


                    puntos += 3;
                    puntuacion.setText("Puntuacion: " +puntos);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, acertado, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    acierto.start(); //this is de sound
                    respuesta1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#76FF03")); //change color to green

                    try {
                        sleep(800);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } //wait for change to other question


                    if(numeroPregunta<9){
                        numeroPregunta+=1;
                        preguntaMostrar(numeroPregunta); //show the next question

                    }else if(numeroPregunta == 9){

                        pantallaImagen.putExtra("puntuacionActual", puntos);
                        startActivity(pantallaImagen); //go to the final activity
                    }
```

Comment: `respuesta1.getText() == respuestaCorrecta` will this work for you?You might need to use `equals()` instead

Comment: You can not use `sleep(800);` in the main UI thread. This will block redrawing the UI until the delay is over. So you do not see the color change. To add a delay before displaying the next question, have a look at `new Handler(new Runnable(){...}).postDelayed(800)`

Comment: OK this answer was useful

Answer (score 0):

what does the `acierto.start();` do?

i think you should put `respuesta1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#76FF03"));` before that.

Comment: acierto.start() put the sound when you click the answer correct. It is a simple MediaPlayer

Answer (score 0):

Can you put more code in the question. Assuming `respuestaCorrecta` is of type String and `respuesta1` is a radioButton with choice on it. `respuesta1.getText()` will give you `CharSequence`, Can you try 

`String choiceSelectedByUser = respuesta1.getText().toString();
if(choiceSelectedByUser == respuestaCorrecta){`

assuming the `respuestaCorrecta` matches the correct answer's `case` (case sensitivity)

Comment: respuesta1 is a button.
respuestaCorrecta have the string answer to other java that it is the data base.

Answer (score 0):

Found the Solution after test and Debug .

```
if(respuesta1.getText().equals(respuestaCorrecta)){
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                // This Code will execute Directly onClick 
                    puntos += 3;
                    puntuacion.setText("Puntuacion: " +puntos);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, acertado, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    acierto.start(); //this is de sound
                    respuesta1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#76FF03"));
                }
            });

            try {
                // Sleep for 200 milliseconds.
                Thread.sleep(800);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // This code will execute after 800 milliseconds
            if(numeroPregunta<9){
                numeroPregunta+=1;
                preguntaMostrar(numeroPregunta); //show the next question
            }else if(numeroPregunta == 9){
                pantallaImagen.putExtra("puntuacionActual", puntos);
                startActivity(pantallaImagen); //go to the final activity
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

And also use `.equals()` instead of `==` to compare Strings